# Juputer Notebook не видит библиотеки

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

при импортировании numpy, pandas и других библиотек, выдает ошибку, хотя все библиотеки установлены. В Чем дело?
[image: Скрин ошибки]

Comment: Так ошибка здесь не из-за библиотек `OSError: [WinError ...]`

Comment: Дело в том что часть библиотек он ищет с CPython а часть в Anaconda, то есть у вас два питона стоит и конфликт скорее всего из за того что ваши ENV не правильно настроены.